# Ansible can't find host file

Tags: ssh, ansible

When I try to run an ansible playbook, while connected to a server I receive the following:

[image: output]

It says that there is no config file found - does anyone know how to change it look in a different location.

Also, I have generated a public key for the target host on the server, and copied it over from id_rsa.pub to the following location: /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys

- however I still get prompted to enter a passphrase.

Are these two issues connected or just happen to be occurring at the same time? Does anybody have any ideas on how to get around this problem?

Will gladly provide more information if needed and any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you have an issue with your ansible installation, (the `python-crypto library` in particular), might be useful if you run `ansible --version` and share the result.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `touch ansible.cfg` will help with the "No config file found" message (it's just informational).

As for the inventory, ansible is finding it (or there would be a "Host file not found" error) but is unable to resolve the host name to a reachable ip address.

It looks like your inventory is missing a `ansible_host` variable for the dns name or ip address of your target host. The host between the red square brackets on the line starting with "fatal:" needs to be resolvable/reachable (eg, ping ) or needs to have that inventory variable set to something that is.

For ssh, it looks like you've put a password protected private key in your `authorized_keys` file. The private key file should be referred to with a `ansible_ssh_private_key_file` variable in the inventory. There are ways to put the key password in the inventory also, but it's not recommended in plaintext and gets more complicated than your current setup. I'd recommend making sure you can manually ssh to the server involved with that key before troubleshooting ansible more.